# can not android ndk result in a better performance

Tags: android, android-ndk

In some computer logic, I think that the native c code (called from java native method) will run fast than java. Then It seems that I have to use ndk in this case.

However google said that:

> Notably, using native code on Android generally does not result in a
>   noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app
>   complexity

So I am confused.  Is ndk necessary?

Comment: Anyone who downvotes this post,can you tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NDK is necessary.  Whether that has anything to do with your case or not is pretty hard to tell, since you haven't given specifics.

Unlike server-side Java, C code can actually be significantly faster than its DVM equivalent.  On the other hand, as the docs point out, it usually isn't.  It takes a significant amount of time to cross the native boundary.  A loop that calls an NDK method will, likely, not see a significant change.  A loop that is implemented entirely on the C side of the NDK may, very well, see significant change.

Note also, that if you choose to use the NDK, you are significantly limiting the devices you support.  You can produce a fat binary that has multiple versions of your lib, one for each supported device.  Of course that affects the size of your app and doesn't guarantee that it will run on some new phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact we are building an android app like `google app` while we have our own arcgis-based geographical data. And we are plan to implement the 3d feature if possible. So in this case do you think the ndk is necessary?

Comment: GIS seems like a classic case for NDK use.  The Java version of ARCGIS was, at least at one time, largely and horribly implemented with JNI.  If 3d were all you needed, OpenGL and a SurfaceView might be enough. Guessing that you will need more...